# How to add URL dynamically to angular service worker DataGroup

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker, cachestorage

I am using `@angular/service-worker` to build a PWA application. Angular service-worker adds the `ngsw-config.json` file, in which you can add a "dataGroups" section to configure cache urls and strategy, etc.

```
    "dataGroups": [{
    "name": "tile-cache",
    "urls": [
    ],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "strategy": "performance",
      "maxSize": 10000,
      "maxAge": "30d"
    }
  }].
```

In my application, I need to add cached urls(like some external map tiles urls) dynamically to the service worker CacheStorage instead of pre-configuring them in dataGroups of the ngsw-config.json file.

I don't see @angular/service-worker exposing any public class or method for doing this.  Is there anyone who knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code for angular service worker](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/service-worker/src/module.ts) there aren't many options for what you want to do. All you have control over is the script path when you're importing `ServiceWorkerModule` into your app module. You can potentially change the script path based on the environment or other factors.

According to the [service worker config docs](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#urls) you can use url patterns in your `ngsw-config.json`. There must be some pattern(s) to the map tiles urls you can define for the dataGroup so you don't have to dynamically/programmatically add the cached urls.

Answer (score 0):

in Angular service worker, there is very limited configuration option is available so, I think you need to modify/update the `ngsw-config.json` using nodejs script, you need to run the script before build your project.